# Using ASP.NET MVC or Web API 2 backend + Angular for dashboard platform

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular, dashboard, platform

I am trying to create a web-based dashboard platform and framework. The techniques I think about using is either ASP.NET MVC 5/6 (backend and frontend integrated) or a ASP.NET Web API 2 backend and an Angular frontend.

The application should function as an application (host), but also as a framework in which applications can be made. An application in this case is a small web application which can be shown on the dashboards.  One of the main bottlenecks I came across is figuring out a way to instantiate the same application multiple times on a dashboard. Since by default doing this introduces ID collision between multiple HTML elements on the web page.

I know Angular kind of 'solves' this problem for you since the scope of your application (looking at an application like it's a component) is maintained by the Angular framework. The reason I mention ASP.NET Web API is because I'd then like to use this as a backend where all the configurations of the applications is stored.

ASP.NET MVC does not (as far as I know) allows you nice ways to handle this, except for rendering the HTML on the server and replacing all HTML ID's to something unique. But even when you manage to do that, you still have the issue of your js files referring to the old not-unique HTML elements. This could then maybe be fixed by using a JS framework that allows you to do such thing.

The reason I ask this question is because I have a lot of experience in the .NET framework and very little experience using Angular. The choice for Angular seems more suited for this use case, but due to my lack of experience in Angular, I am not able to make an arguable choice. I have some experience in ASP.NET MVC specifically, but not enough to also think of a nice way of handling the ID collision issue.

Therefore my question to you, the StackOverflow community, is do you have any experience using any of these frameworks? And if so, what would you choose and why do you think the choice is better suited for the job?

Comment: I got  a quick look yesterday at angular-ide ... and looks like an interesting approach of building your angular application in this editor or (maybe some other), and using exclusively angular services to access your ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: Angular IDE is as it says, an IDE. Which I'm not specifically looking for. I look for a motivated and considerate choice to either choose ASP.NET MVC or Angular. But thanks for you comment. Might be handy when I eventually end up choosing Angular

Answer (score 0):

Use angular 2 (or 4) and webapi. Through use of components and parameterized directives, that can solve it. If you need good authentication, that will have to be dealt separately.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also think Angular is a possible and nice solution, but due to my inexperience with Angular I am also curious if anyone would consider using ASP.NET MVC in some combination with a JS framework which handles the ID collision.

Comment: Mvc with knockout does that. Being mvvm, each input or other control binds with a knockout property. Knockout js can also call webapi directly with jquery.ajax and update ui values at the go. It is a solution in itself also.